# React Application npm start is giving an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to run my React app in the local environment and keep getting the following error

```
PS  npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Documents\business-website-react-master\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\\Documents\business-website-react-master\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\\_logs\2020-02-22T20_12_59_502Z-debug.log
```

Here is what the folder directory looks like as well.

[image: screenshot]

the `package.json` file is still there so i don't understand why the file cannot be located.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `package.json` file should be in the root folder, same where you are typing `npm start`. Currently it is located in the `src` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, **npm** does not find `package.json` file. The reason in your case is that the file is located in the `src` folder. Once you move the file into the root - where you tried to run earlier - and run `npm start` then it should be just starting fine.

If the `node_modules` folder is also missing - which is containing all the installed dependencies to run your project - then you need to run first `npm install` which will take all the dependencies from `package.json` and install them.

I hope that helps!

Comment: it now says `npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`

Comment: @RC96 Just extended my answer but yes, as it says you need to install the dependencies first.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the npm err when I was trying to download react for the first time. I tried all the things that were suggested here and was only able to get 2 different json folders on seperate occasions. That was it the package-lock.json as well as just package.json. Grandpa always said, "Go to the root of the problem." Then I went back to node.js. I chose the repair option. While that was running, I was still reading options and saw someone suggested npm install -g npm. The repair had completed as I was starting to type that in. So not sure which was the fix. I wanted to share the repair on node.js because I didn't see anyone else suggesting that... Hope this helps!